# Changes to Ubuntu are mysteriously rolled back

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

I am running Ubuntu server 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-130. It is running on a Virtual Machine and I only have access to it through SSH. It's primary use is as a web server. No problems with it for almost two years.

I have recently come across a strange problem. Any changes I make to the system although they are happening, after some time (a few minutes) they are "rolled back" and are as if they never happened. These changes are:

- file system changes: copy or delete files. The newly copied files cannot be found and the deleted files appear again
- database changes
- file permission and ownership changes i.e. chmod and chown
- and finally, the most scary thing, I changed my password, rebooted Ubuntu, SSH'd using the new password and I was logged in. After I tried to login again, like 15 minutes later, I had to use the old password as the new one was not accepted...

What is going on? Do you have any idea? Could it be compromised?

In addition to the above, SSH sessions are terminating unexpectedly with a "Software error: Connection aborted". I have tried Putty and Bitvise SSH client and the results are the same.

Thank you in advance for any advices.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you checked system logs (`/var/log`) for anything suspicious?

Comment: I am not sure... Here https://pastebin.com/D4UhjxpM you can find the latest entries from /var/log/syslog

Comment: Could the disk be full?

Comment: /dev/sda1 has 75G available so this doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks

Comment: After running `last` it shows a peculiar entry `reboot   system boot  4.4.0-130-generi Fri Jul 13 16:35   still running`. How can the boot appear as running 4 days later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out what was wrong so I am posting an answer in case someone faces similar issues. The problem was caused by the VM host provider where by mistake they had put online two instances of my VM. As the two instances had the same IP address, whenever i accessed the server through SSH I was randomly connected to one the two instances, which explains the inconsistencies. After shutting down one instance all problems were resolved.
Thank you all for your comments on this.